# Turn everything into "..." after the ; which is on the 100th position in the sentence

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here I have a string: "status; status;" and so on...
I need to cut the string from the status where string is longer than 100 chars

for example:
"status; status; status; (here is longer than 100 chars) ..."

previously I did it with the array:

```
 if($length_of_string > 100)
 { 
     $number_of_elements = count($statuses_array);
     echo $statuses_array[$number_of_elements-1];
     echo ' ... ';
     } else {
     echo $string_of_statuses;
}
```

but it is not good

thank you in advance!

Comment: "but it is not good". How so?

Comment: Use $string = substr($string,0,100);http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: @Mihai, but it can show me like this: "status; status; sta"

Comment: I don't get you,you mean,it doesn't need to be exactly 100,but if >100 it will also include the truncated element?

Comment: @Mihai I need to show the string (if it is longer than 100 chars) liike this: "status; stat(Here string is longer than 100 chars)us; ..." That is it... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$l = strlen($status_string);
if ($l > 100) {
   //Split string into array of statuses, to not break last status
   $ls = explode(";",$status_string);
   $new_status = "";
   $i = 0;
   //Check if there is room for the next status in $new_status without passing 100 chars
   while (strlen($new_status) < 100) {
      $new_status .= $ls[$i].";";
      $i++;
   }
   $new_status = substr($new_status,0,-1)."...";
}
```

Edit: simplified code, as the last status apparently can surpass 100 chars, which actually makes it easier

Comment: No problem, I hope it does what you wanted it to. Please remember to accept the answer if it did.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question right, and I think I am: if a string is longer than 100 characters, append a ellipsis to the first 100 characters.

If so, then you don't necessarily need a `regex`, or a `preg_replace`. You can do it simply as follows:

```
$status_length = strlen($status_string);

$status = '';

if ($status_length > 100) {
   //get the substring up to the first 100 characters:
   $status = substr($status_string, 0, 100);

   //now append the ellipsis to it:
   $status .= '...';
}

echo $status;
```

Comment: I need to show the string (if it is longer than 100 chars) liike this: "status; stat(Here string is longer than 100 chars)us; ..." That is it... Thank you!

Comment: @user2586329, I am horribly confused at how you posed desired result - in that if the string is longer than 100 characters you want an ellipsis, but only after a whole occurrence of `"status;"`? Is that correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what he means, yes... please see my answer for a solution to that

Comment: @ipoga, alright - thanks! BTW, it may bode you well to work in Cryptography - because to me the OP wasn't clear, at all!

Answer (score 0):

your variable 
`$variable_text="status; status; status; status; status; status; status; status; status; status; status; status; statwus; status; status; status; status; status;";`

a number after you want to add "..."
`$characters=100;`

count words in **$variable_text**
`$words_number=preg_split("/[\s]+/", $variable_text);`

Add words to the variable **$words**. If characters in the variable **$words** is less than variable **$characters(100)** a word is added to variable **$result**. If hundredth character is in a word "sta(100)tus;" this word is not added to variable **$result**

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($words_number);$i++){
    $words=$words." ".$words_number[$i];
    if(strlen($words)<$characters){
        $result=$words;
    }
}
```

if your variable **$variable_text** is bigger than variable **$result** add " ..." at the end

```
if(strlen($result)<strlen($variable_text)){
    $result=$result." ...";
}
```

show the result
`echo $result;`